# Replace NULL with custom text inside the concatenation function SQL

Tags: sql, null, concatenation

I want to concatenate the output if it belongs to the same id, so I use the following function, but I also want to replace null values ​​with custom text, how do I do it right?

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(ps_state.name, 'No-State') SEPARATOR ', ')
```

All code if needed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ps_customer.id_customer AS CustomersId, ps_customer.email AS CustomersName, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(ps_state.name, 'No') SEPARATOR ', ') AS StatesName, 
GROUP_CONCAT(ps_country_lang.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS CountryName 
FROM ps_customer
INNER JOIN ps_address ON ps_customer.id_customer=ps_address.id_customer
LEFT JOIN ps_state ON ps_state.id_state=ps_address.id_state
INNER JOIN ps_country_lang ON ps_country_lang.id_country=ps_address.id_country
WHERE ps_country_lang.id_lang=1
GROUP BY ps_customer.id_customer, ps_state.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically looks right but I would use `coalesce()`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(coalesce(ps_state.name, 'No-State') SEPARATOR ', ')
```

You might also want to order within the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, if there is an ordering that you want or expect.

Comment: Indeed, the mistake was different. It was all about GROUP BY, I had to remove `ps_state.name` from there.